# Why does a NIC need to support VLAN tags

Tags: network-adapter, vlan

In some ways, I'm still trying to wrap my head around VLAN sometimes.

As far as I'm aware, there are two ways to deal with VLANs (820.1Q):

1. Portbased VLANs
2. Tagged VLANs

**Portbased VLANs** are sufficient if all that's needed is a single Ethernet-Switch. I'm assuming in this case, the Switch keeps an internal lookup table to determine which port is associated with each VLAN.

**Tagged VLANs** are needed once I connect multiple Switches, to avoid needing an extra cable between each VLAN. That way I can use a trunk that allows multiple vlans.

As far as I'm aware, all of this is happening on the Switch side of things, so I don't see the need to associate a NIC to a VLAN.

Is it simply used to provide additional security? Can someone shed some light on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a port based VLAN the endpoint doesn't have to know anything. If you don't the endpoint has to tag his own packets. You never mentioned anything about NIC assignment so that's my best guess as to what you mean.

How tagging works depends on your OS but obviously you need to tell it somehow that packets that leave your machine through that connection should be tagged as XY.

In addition as we're working on layer two your NIC handles most of it and as such needs to be able to interpret the 802.1Q tags if they arrive on that interface. If they do it's likely that you want to use that information in some manner.

Nobody is stopping you from running your trunk to an endpoint that does stuff with it. Stuff in this case might refer to a lot of different things. A simple example would be routing. If you're receiving multiple packets that are tagged through a single port and implement routing for those VLANs you will have to send out packets that are tagged accordingly. Another example would be a virtualization solution (ignoring the magic that's inside) it would need to be able to send tagged packets if you want different VMs to use different VLANs.

Comment: Would you be so kind to list some examples when tagging an endpoint would/could be useful? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you want to implement routing as you need to send out differently tagged packets or if you run some kind of virtualization solution and want to assign your VMs a VLAN.